# AWS Fargate Task Debugging, what does "CannotPullContainerError ... invalid reference format" mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-container, aws-fargate, aws-ecs

I have docker container stored on AWS ECR, using this container I have created Task . When I run Task over Fargate , the service moves from PROVISIONING > PENDING (red color) > STOPPED states .

There is no log either in Service Event , or CloudWatch . Absolutely no way to know what is the real problem .

Any idea which way to move, AWS document did not helped.

Comment: I followed these [instructions] (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/stopped-task-errors.html) . And now I can see that the error it shows for Task provisioning is **Status reason  CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): invalid reference format** . Again this does not help anyway. Any pointer on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this error also.
In my case the problem was that I had an invalid `image` value in my container definition.  The image is generally a repository_url and image tag as per `image` instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html

Comment: Wow. Just ran into this working on a 2nd service in Fargate with a semi-complex file set up. Totally botched the image pointing to the one in the repo. Would have loved something telling me this (other than your answer)!

Answer (score 2):

The AWS Fargate has a simple but scuttle info missing , this is what has lead you to your issue .Let me explain step by step.

First step is to create a Task definition , when you do that you can define

```
 Entry point ["/bin/ls"]
Command     [">","/list.txt","|","echo","/list.txt"]
```

This is equivalient to /bin/ls > /list.txt | echo /list.txt .

Please note the spaces in between has to be replaced by comma. What AWS Farget team forgot was that in the TaskDefinition > Add Container section in the wizard , this comma delimiter echo,helloworld is provided in the text box [![enter image description here][1]][1]. But in the Task form there is not such info . This is very confusing.

One last thing , AWS Fargate has very limited info for debugging. Here are my tips

- You can get only possible error under
  Cluster>Task>{TaskName}>{container} . Under reason for error.
- If the error is very small , I always got Error Code0 , no space between Code0. Nothing on Cloud watch as well .
- If the error text is big (may be around 20 char or > ) you will get it both in the #1 and the CloudWatch log.

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow this helped :)

Comment: Is there any way to get more info about reason:Error Code0?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you need to add permissions in your ECR. In your repository there is a tab their called permissions. Add those permissions you think you need.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc mentions, this is usually a wrong DockerHub/repo image name.

In my case it was because the image name was calculated by an environment variable, in my Docker Compose file:

```
services:
  web:
    image: scipilot/my-web-app:$MY_VERSION_TAG
```

And I'd missed setting the environment variable when using `ecs-cli compose service up`. So Fargate was probably trying to pull "scipilot/my-web-app:" from Docker Hub, hence an invalid format error.