# Cannot pull container Invalid reference format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, dockerhub, aws-fargate

I have created a docker image and pushed to dockerhub
https://cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/annamalai2k11/helloworld

now I need to setup fargate -amazon ECS to pull the docker image.
I have configure image uri like this
annamalai2k11/helloworld

it's giving cannot pull container invalid reference format

Comment: Can you check your task events and see if this was because a tag was missing? Can you try docker.io/annamalai2k11/helloworld:latest?

Comment: Is this private docker registry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Fargate Task Debugging, what does "CannotPullContainerError ... invalid reference format" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843530/aws-fargate-task-debugging-what-does-cannotpullcontainererror-invalid-refe)